# Wrong dates shown in Jekyll-based blog

Tags: yaml, jekyll, blogs

I have posted two posts to [my blog](http://codeapprentice.info) in the past two days. As you can see, both are dated Nov 1, 2017. I correctly named the files with their respective dates as you can see in [the github repofor this blog](https://github.com/codeguru42/code-apprentice/tree/master/_posts). What is going on here? Why do the posts show the wrong date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have in the YML the following date:

```
2017-10-20 0800:00:00 -0600
```

This should be:

```
2017-10-20 08:00:00 -0600
```

(The first colon is preceded by too many zero's)

Comment: Alternatively, the first colon is preceded by too many zeros. Thanks for the catch.